# php file_get_contents return bool(false) ? on geoplugin.net/json

Tags: php, json

I have got this code to get the Code to get the Geolocation:

Please note this is most probably the first time am seeing that error. I cant tell wherether the Geo Services are offline or what's really going on.

```
try{
$json = @file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip='.getIp());


if($json === false){

    throw new Exception('You are not connected to the internet');


}else{
echo 'Great';
}
}catch( Exception $e){

}

function getIp(){

$ip = "";

    if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
{
//check for ip from share internet
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
{
// Check for the Proxy User
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
else
{
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}

var_dump($ip);
// This will print user's real IP Address
// does't matter if user using proxy or not.
return $ip;
    }
```

It keeps on throwing the `'You are not connected to the internet';`

What could be the issue??

Thank you!!

Comment: Remove the `@` and you should see. Also use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Still the Same... just Tried Now... See image http://ctrlv.in/472054

Comment: Get rid of the  `try` / `catch` temporarily.

Comment: Now I get: `Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=112.209.154.197) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found i`;

Comment: allow_url_fopen=On in php.ini or use cURL to retrieve data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't use the @ if possible.  This suppresses errors, but if you;re getting errors, then you need to know about it as it means something isn't right....

The problem you;re having relates to an option in php.ini.  check out [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

PHP seems to disallow opening remote files (URL's) unless you have explicitly enabled that feature, hence you always get a `false` returned...

I hope that helps!